How to change the content of a NavigationView (Lepoco WPFUI)?
Recently, I am making a project, which involves in using WebSocket. However, after I received the message on MainPageWindow.xaml.cs, I have to change the content of a label on FriendPage.xaml (An User Interface), which is loaded by a NavigationView of Lepoco WPFUI.

Here is a sample of what I am taking about:
        <ui:NavigationView x:Name="NavigationView_menu" Background="White" Margin="0,0,-20,10" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" HeaderVisibility="Hidden" CompactPaneLength="40" IsManipulationEnabled="True" IsPaneOpen="False" IsPaneToggleVisible="False">
            <ui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <ui:NavigationViewItem Content="Friends" TargetPageType="{x:Type pages:FriendPage}">
                    <ui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <ui:FontIcon Glyph="&#xf0c0;" FontFamily="{StaticResource Font Awesome 6 Free Solid}" FontSize="30" Foreground="White"/>
                    </ui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </ui:NavigationViewItem>
        </ui:NavigationView>

Project
|
|---MainPageWindow.xaml          <- NavigationView code here, which includes FriendPage.xaml
|---MainPageWindow.xaml.cs       <- I want to change the content of the label here
|---navigationview_page
    |
    |---FriendPage.xaml          <- Label defined here
    |---FriendPage.xaml.cs


I searched the internet and found few similar problems, but they are not using Lepoco WPFUI, and the code is not working. I also tried to see if there is a GetContent method I can use, but I can not find one.

I also tried this tonight, and it will print False while it will still show a null reference exception when trying to change the text.
Trace.WriteLine("00000000000000000");
NavigationView_menu.Navigate(typeof(ProfilePage));
Trace.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------");
ProfilePage profilePage = NavigationView_menu.DataContext as ProfilePage;
Thread.Sleep(100);
Trace.WriteLine("111111111111111111123"+profilePage == null);
profilePage.textbox_username.Text = "1234";


In this case, I am wondering how could I do that.

In fact, we can get the page by using some easy method:
        private static FriendPage page;
        public static FriendPage Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return page;
            }
            private set
            {
                page = value;
            }
        }

        public FriendPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Instance = this;
        }

Because there is only one page created by NavigationView, this method can work.

While I did not worked with this library and hopefully understood your questions correctly, the solution is to create a simple messaging system would be enough to resolve it. For reference please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.mvvm.messaging.weakreferencemessenger?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.1.
